# JavaScript Elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need help with the following:

I have a page with h3-s and paragraphs and I want all the paragraphs to initially be hidden.

If a h3 is clicked, the script will loop through the tags below it, showing the paragraph tags, if it comes to another h3 tag it should break out the loop.

**I have no control over the html output so I can't nest the tags or give any of the h3-s ids. The code below is all i have to play with**.

E.g. If H3 Title2 is clicked, then Title 2 Para 1 and Title 2 Para 2 are shown, if H3 Title2 is clicked again then Title 2 Para 1 and Title 2 Para 2 are hidden.

```
<h3>H3 Title1</h3>
<p>Title 1 Para 1</p>
<p>Title 1 Para 2</p>
<p>Title 1 Para 3</p>
<p>Title 1 Para 4</p>


<h3>H3 Title2</h3>
<p>Title 2 Para 1</p>
<p>Title 2 Para 2</p>


<h3>H3 Title3</h3>
<p>Title 3 Para 1</p>
<p>Title 3 Para 2</p>


<h3>H3 Title4</h3>
<p>Title 4 Para 1</p>
<p>Title 4 Para 2</p>
<p>Title 4 Para 3</p>
```

No jQuery please

Comment: So you cant fix your broken markup, and you can't use a decent library for DOM manipulation. Thats a shame. Either of those options would make this much easier to answer.

Comment: Do you have an attempt to do it yourself or just want us to write your code?

Comment: i had got this far 'code'window.onload = function() { paragraphtags() ; }

  function paragraphtags() {

    var container = document.getElementById("bodytag");
   
     if (container != null) {
     
       var h3 = container.getElementsByTagName('h3');

         for(i=0; i<h3.length; i++) { 
           h3[i].addEventListener("click",dealWithLink, false);
         }
       
     }
   
  }



  function dealWithLink() { 
   
   alert(this);
   
  }'code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) to get all the H3s on your page, you want to attach a click() handler to those.

In your onclick you loop over all the next elements until you get to an H3 and break out of the loop. Take a look at [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling) for getting the elements after the H3.

For showing/hiding either set a css class or directly change the element's style toggling between `display:block` and `display:none`.

Comment: Note that `nextElementSibling` does not work in Internet Explorer before v9.

Comment: @xqwzts thanks you so much, i managed to get this to work.      var sib = this.nextElementSibling;
 
   while( sib.nodeName != "H3" ) {
    sib.style.display = "block";
    sib =  sib.nextElementSibling;
   }

Answer (score 1):

Something like..

```
var pHide = function () {
    var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p'), i = ps.length;
    while(i-->0) ps[i].style.display = 'none';
},
toggleDisplay = function (elm) {
    elm.style.display = elm.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
},
nextNode = function (elm) { // can't assume built in?
    var e = elm;
    while( e = e.nextSibling ) if ( e.tagName !== undefined ) break;
    return e;
},
addActions = function () {
    var hs = document.getElementsByTagName('h3'), i = hs.length;
    while(i-->0) hs[i].addEventListener('click',function () {
        var elm = this;
        while( (elm = nextNode(elm)) && elm.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'h3') if(elm.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'p') toggleDisplay(elm);
    }, false);

};
pHide();
addActions();​
```

Example [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zKSEt/)

Comment: +1 for correct code (if a little tricky to read!). I've corrected your typo of `stlye` to `style`.

Comment: @lonesomeday thanks, but it wasn't correct until the edit I did after that because I assumed a '.nextNode' which isn't native, added it in now

Comment: @lonesomeday I'm struggling to get this code to work, it hides the paragraphs but doesn't do anything when an h3 is clicked :(

Comment: @Scott tagName needed to be converted `toLowerCase`, I'll edit it in and give a jsfiddle. Remember that the script needs to be run after the DOM has loaded the HTML

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with [xqwzts'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501759/xqwzts) answer: Get a reference to the clicked H3 element, iterate over the following nodes and inspect them (type and name).

Here is another, maybe easier to read solution:

```
// the event handler we are going to use
var handler = function() {
    // `this` refers to the clicked element
    var node = this.nextSibling;
    // iterate over all following nodes
    for(; node ; node = node.nextSibling) {
        if(node.nodeName === 'P') {
            // if it is a p element, toggle the visibility
            node.style.display = node.style.display === 'block' ? '' : 'block';
        }
        else if(node.nodeName === 'H3') { // or node.nodeType === 1
            break; // if it is a H3 element (or an element but not P), stop
        }
    }
};

// get all h3 elements
var h3s = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

// assign a click event handler to all of them
for(var i = 0, l = h3s.length; i < l; i++) {
    h3s[i].onclick = handler;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UwLhJ/)

There are various ways to bind event handlers, all of which are well explained at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

**Reference:** [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName), [`Node#nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeName), [`Node#nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType), [`Element#style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style)